# How to count records by branch and year sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to count projects by branch and by the year.
I tried this code but does not work. Any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT        COUNT(ProjectIndentID) AS NoOfProjects, BranchID, DATEPART(year, PIDate) AS Expr1
FROM            dbo.ProjectIndent
GROUP BY BranchID, PIDate
HAVING        (DATEPART(year, PIDate) = '2016')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `group by` the year, not the date:

```
SELECT COUNT(ProjectIndentID) AS NoOfProjects, BranchID,
       DATEPART(year, PIDate) AS yr
FROM  dbo.ProjectIndent
WHERE DATEPART(year, PIDate) = 2016
GROUP BY BranchId, DATEPART(year, PIDate) ;
```

In addition:

- The `having` logic should really be in a `where` clause.  It is better to filter the data *before* aggregation, rather than afterwords.
- `DATEPART()` returns an integers, so use `2016` rather than `'2016'`.
- You probably want an `ORDER BY`.
- The `WHERE` clause should really be `WHERE PIDate >= '2016-01-01' AND PIDate < '2017-01-01'.  This allows an index to be used for the filtering (if appropriate).